# Child Class is Serializable into a file, but the file is not Deserializable

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

We have a super class called "Vehicle", that implements the marker interface Serializable.
Then we have a child class called "Car", that inherits "Vehicle", thus the child class "Car" also implements the Serializable marker interface, because of it's parent "Vehicle".

Now we can Serialize any instance of a Vehicle to a File, without any problems.
But when we try to perform Deserialization of that File, to an Object of type "Car", then the program throws an Exception.

The way I solved this is by implementing the Serializable marker interface manually in the "Car" class.

Why is that the case? From all things I read on Serialization today, nobody seems to cover this issue.

The conclusion I came to is the following: When the "Car" class inherits the "Vehicle" class, it also inherits the interface implemented in "Vehicle", thus the "Car" object is serializable, but once we serialize an instance of the "Car" object to a File (for example: "car1.ser"), the "car1.ser" file has an object written to it, with all of it's modifiers, attributes, methods and etc.
But somehow the object of type "Car", that is written to the "car1.ser" file, does not inherit the "Serializable" marker from it's parent. What is the reason for that, I am not really sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exception? (please consider to add it to the post, since it seems like an "important detail")

Sorry, cannot re-produce/comprehend:

```
package com.example.serial;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class SerialTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Car car = new Car();
    car.manufacturer = "Toyota";
    car.model = "Land Cruiser";
    
    // tmp memory:
    ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    // write object:
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(outStream);
    oos.writeObject(car);

    // input stream of "tmp memory":
    ByteArrayInputStream inStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outStream.toByteArray());

    // read object:
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(inStream);
    Car c2 = (Car) ois.readObject();

    // print/verify:
    System.out.println(c2);
  }
}

class Vehicle implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;
  String manufacturer;
}

class Car extends Vehicle {

  String model;
}
```

Prints:

```
com.example.serial.Car@1ed6993a
```

We can also do:

```java
Vehicle car = new Car();
// ... same code, but without "model"
```

But not:

```
Vehicle car = new Vehicle();
...
```

..this will lead to:

```text
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.example.serial.Vehicle cannot be cast to class com.example.serial.Car
```

at this line:

```
Car c2 = (Car) ois.readObject();
```

Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/serialization/serial-arch.html

Comment: Tomorrow I will post the whole project on GitHub and leave the link in my post. I probably have smelly code. Anyways, the Exception I am getting is "InvalidClassException".

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer, you really did take the time to write it and second of all I am really sorry. I looked thoroughly through my code again and the problem was a very silly one, I had a typo on the file location.

Comment: glad you found the typo..but still InvalidClassException? "Thrown when the Serialization runtime detects one of the following problems with a Class.
1.The *serial version* of the class does not match that of the class descriptor read from the stream
2.The class contains *unknown datatypes*
3.The class *does not have an accessible no-arg constructor"* that was from [java7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InvalidClassException.html)

Comment: until [java 17](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InvalidClassException.html) additionally: "4.The ObjectStreamClass of an *enum constant* does not represent an *enum type*
5. Other conditions given in the *Java Object Serialization Specification*"

Comment: (I tested with java17)

Comment: So I had written: ObjectInputStream objIn = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("car1.txt")); SHOULD HAVE BEEN: ObjectInputStream objIn = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("car1.ser"));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241052/discussion-between-nightboy-and-xerx593).